# Vuejs - Child component method run before parent query done running

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, components

I'm working on a basic POC app that has a Solr search function on the front that finds products, and then links in the search results use a route to go to a Product detail page.

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Search from '@/components/Search'
import Product from '@/components/Product'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/search',
      name: 'Search',
      component: Search
    },
    {
      path: '/product_display/:language/:entity_id',
      name: 'product_display',
      component: Product
    },
  ]
})
```

**Product.vue**

```
<template>
  <section class="hero is-warning">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        {{ product.ss_field_content_title }}
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <productSlideshow :slideshowNid="product.is_product_slideshow" 
      :language="product.ss_language"></productSlideshow>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import ProductSlideshow from '@/components/ProductSlideshow'

export default {
  name: 'Product',
  components: {
    ProductSlideshow
  },
  data () {
    return {
      product: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getProduct()
  },
  methods: {
    getProduct: function () {
      const params = new URLSearchParams()
      var entityId = this.$route.params.entity_id
      var language = this.$route.params.language
      params.append('fq', 'bundle:product_display')
      params.append('fq', 'entity_id:' + entityId)
      params.append('fq', 'ss_language:' + language)
      params.append('wt', 'json')
      params.append('rows', 1)
      axios.get('https://my.solrurl.com/solr/indexname/select', {
        params: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.product = response.data.response.docs[0]
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'getProduct'
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Getting to this page works fine. The problem is getting the necessary params to the child ProductSlideshow component.

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ slideshow.label }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'ProductSlideshow',
  props: {
    slideshowNid: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    language: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      slideshow: {},
      slides: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getSlideshow()
  },
  methods: {
    getSlideshow: function () {
      var language = this.language
      // Get slideshow record from Solr.
      const params = new URLSearchParams()
      params.append('fq', 'bundle:slideshow')
      params.append('fq', 'entity_id:' + this.slideshowNid)
      params.append('fq', 'ss_language:' + language)
      params.append('fq', 'entity_type:node')
      params.append('wt', 'json')
      params.append('rows', 1)
      axios.get('https://my.solrurl.com/solr/indexname/select', {
        params: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.slideshow = response.data.response.docs[0]
        this.slides = this.slideshow.sm_field_slideshow_home
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'getSlideshow'
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

What I'm seeing is no data returned from the Solr query for the slideshow record, and when inspecting the Solr query, it was because *language* was undefined in the query, so nothing could be returned.  By using various debugger breakpoints, I figured out that what's happening is that *getSlideshow()* is being called before the results are returned from *getProduct()* in the Product component. I tried removing the *created()* method in the ProductDisplay component, but that didn't make a difference.

What do I need to change so that my *getSlideshow()* method in the ProductSlideshow component doesn't get called until the query from the Product component has been completed?

Comment: the created event of your slideshow is no a good place to do that. You will not know for sure that your promise of the getproduct is completed. there are multiple solutions to do this, make us of the promise of your get call, watch, use events, a computed property of your product page that is bound to the 'ProductSlideshow' component ... can you make a plunkr so we can help in a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue connected with the fact, that Vue fires `created` hooks in sync way, so all children templates are created and mounted before the response from API comes.
The solution is to use [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

In your `Product.vue` component create some Boolean value like `isProductFetched` and render the child only when this value will be true.

```
<template>
  <section class="hero is-warning">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        {{ product.ss_field_content_title }}
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <productSlideshow 
      v-if="isProductFetched"
      :slideshowNid="product.is_product_slideshow" 
      :language="product.ss_language"></productSlideshow>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import ProductSlideshow from '@/components/ProductSlideshow'

export default {
  name: 'Product',
  components: {
    ProductSlideshow
  },
  data () {
    return {
     isProductFetched: false,
     product: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getProduct()
  },
  methods: {
    getProduct: function () {
      const params = new URLSearchParams()
      var entityId = this.$route.params.entity_id
      var language = this.$route.params.language
      params.append('fq', 'bundle:product_display')
      params.append('fq', 'entity_id:' + entityId)
      params.append('fq', 'ss_language:' + language)
      params.append('wt', 'json')
      params.append('rows', 1)
      axios.get('https://my.solrurl.com/solr/indexname/select', {
        params: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.product = response.data.response.docs[0]
        
        // At this point, the product is fetched
       this.isProductFetched = true
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'getProduct'
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

As a result, the child component won't be rendered until this value becomes `true.`  Also, do not forget to handle the error case.

Comment: Sorry @yevhenii-herasymchuk, this is the first chance I've had to look at this. To answer your question, no. I implemented it as you showed it, but it appears that the ProductSlideshow component is never loaded. I set some breakpoints, and it looks as though getSlideshow() is never called. It's almost as if it's past the point in the cycle where it can be loaded.

Comment: Actually, it did work. I realized that I still had the created method commented out, so getSlideshow() wasn't even being called. Once I enabled that, it worked perfectly.